# What are the final steps to arrive at the transfer function for this RCL circuit?

Tags: analog, circuit-design, transfer-function

What are the final steps to arrive at the transfer function for this RCL circuit?

I am attempting to arrive at this transfer function $$\dfrac{V_o(s)}{V_i(s)}=\dfrac{sL}{CL(R_1+R_2)s^2+(R_1R_2C+L)s+R_1}$$ for the following RCL circuit.

[image]

My initial problem was not knowing the correct steps to take to get from the circuit to the final TF, using the complex impedance method.

So, I have now used the KVL method, which has got me to a final transfer function. But, not the one that I desire.

$$\dfrac{I_2(s)}{V_1(s)}=\dfrac{s^2CL}{CL(R_1+R_2)s^2+(R_1R_2C+L)s+R_1}$$

Therefore, I would just like to know whether or not the last remaining step is to take \$V_o = I_2(s)Z_c\$, where \$Z_c = \frac{1}{sC}\$ and therefore multiply \$I_2(s)\$ by \$\frac{1}{sC}\$ and thus reduce the numerator from \$s^2CL\$ to \$sL\$

So, these are the steps taken using KVL:

Loop 1:

$$V_1(s) - I_1(s)R_1 - L(sI_1(s)-sI_2(s)) = 0$$

$$I_1(s)(R_1 + sL)- sLI_2(s) = V_1(s)\tag{1}$$

Loop 2:

$$I_2(s)R_2 + \frac{I_2(s)}{sC} + L(sI_2(s)-sI_1(s)) = 0$$

$$-sLI_1(s)+I_2(s)(sL+R_2+\frac{1}{sC}) = 0\tag{2}$$

From (2) I get that \$I_1\$

$$I_1=I_2(s)(sL+R_2+\frac{1}{sC})\frac{1}{sL}$$

$$I_1=I_2(s)(1+\frac{R_2}{sL}+\frac{1}{s^2CL})\tag{3}$$

which, when substituted into (1), gives

$$I_2(s)(1+\frac{R_2}{sL}+\frac{1}{s^2CL})(sL+R_1) - sLI_2(s) = V_1(s)\tag{4}$$

Multiplying through by \$(sL+R_1)\$

$$I_2(s)(sL+\frac{sLR_2}{sL}+\frac{sL}{s^2CL}+R_1+\frac{R_1R_2}{sL}+\frac{R_1}{s^2CL})-sLI_2(s)= V_1(s)\tag{5}$$

Multiplying through by \$I_2(s)\$

$$sLI_2(s)+\frac{sLR_2}{sL}I_2(s)+\frac{sL}{s^2CL}I_2(s)+R_1I_2(s)+\frac{R_1R_2}{sL}I_2(s)+\frac{R_1}{s^2CL}I_2(s)-sLI_2(s)= V_1(s)\tag{6}$$

cancelling out like terms, I get

$$\frac{sLR_2}{sL}I_2(s)+\frac{sL}{s^2CL}I_2(s)+R_1I_2(s)+\frac{R_1R_2}{sL}I_2(s)+\frac{R_1}{s^2CL}I_2(s)= V_1(s)$$

factoring out \$I_2(s)\$, I get

$$I_2(s)(\frac{R_1}{s^2CL}+\frac{R_1R_2}{sL}+\frac{1}{sC}+R_1+R_2)= V_1(s)\tag{7}$$

obtaining a common denominator, I get the following

$$I_2(s)(\frac{R_1}{s^2CL}+\frac{sR_1R_2C+sL}{s^2CL}+R_1+R_2)= V_1(s)\tag{8}$$

$$I_2(s)(\frac{R_1}{s^2CL}+\frac{sR_1R_2C+sL+s^2CL(R_1+R_2)}{s^2CL})= V_1(s)\tag{9}$$

factoring out the \$1/s^2CL\$, I get

$$\frac{I_2(s)}{s^2CL}(R_1+sR_1R_2C+sL+s^2CL(R_1+R_2)= V_1(s)\tag{10}$$

Rearranging in terms of \$I_2(s)\$ and \$V_1(s)\$, I get

$$\dfrac{I_2(s)}{V_1(s)}=\dfrac{s^2CL}{CL(R_1+R_2)s^2+(R_1R_2C+L)s+R_1}\tag{11}$$

So, is the last step to take \$V_o = I_2(s)Z_c\$, where \$Z_c = \frac{1}{sC}\$ and therefore multiply \$I_2(s)\$ by \$\frac{1}{sC}\$ whereby reducing the numerator from \$s^2CL\$ to \$sL\$?

Comment: A thought just crossed my mind. Is it correct to assume that Vo = I_2(s) x Zc and therefore, can divide I_2(s) by 1/sC and thus reduce the numerator to sL?

Comment: The original transfer function looks right. The one at top of your question. Are you just trying to figure out how it gets made?

Comment: Or do you want the voltage gain, \$K\$?

Comment: @jonk I am trying to figure out how to get to the the original transfer function. Tried the complex impedance method first and couldn't quite get there. So, I thought I'd try the KVL method, which has brought me closer to the original TF. So, just trying to confirm the last couple of steps to get output voltage/input voltage TF!

Comment: I'll post something, then. I've not checked my work and I may have made a mistake in it. But I'm just following a "mental flowchart" that I usually apply with success. So you can see if it fits your needs. (I had copied some text I had to correct. Sorry about that.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your schematic is as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2friaUV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Above, you can see that \$R_2\$ and \$Z_2\$ form a voltage divider that divides \$V_Y\$ into \$V_\text{OUT}\$. It follows that:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Each Stage}
\left\{
  \begin{array}{rl}
V_\text{OUT} = V_Y\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_2}{Z_2}}&&Z_2 = \left(Z_{C_1}\mid\mid \infty\right)=Z_{C_1}\\\\
V_Y = V_\text{IN}\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_1}{Z_1}}&&Z_1 = Z_{L_1}\mid\mid \left(Z_2 + R_2\right)
  \end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}$$
$$\therefore \frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_1}{Z_1}}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_2}{Z_2}}$$

From that, I get:

$$H\left(s\right)=\frac{L_1\,s}{L_1\,C_1\left(R_1+R_2\right)s^2+\left(R_1\,R_2\,C_1+L_1\right)s+R_1}$$

That is not in standard form, though. To get started, you want to divide through so that you isolate \$s^2\$ in the denominator. So, something like this to start:

$$H\left(s\right)=\frac{\frac{1}{C_1\left(R_1+R_2\right)}\,s}{s^2+\frac{R_2\,C_1+\frac{L_1}{R_1}}{L_1\,C_1\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)}\,s+\frac{1}{L_1\,C_1\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)}}$$

Set \$\alpha=\frac12\cdot \frac{R_2\,C_1+\frac{L_1}{R_1}}{L_1\,C_1\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)}\$, \$\omega_{_0}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L_1\,C_1\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)}}\$, and create the unitless damping factor of \$\zeta=\frac{\alpha}{\omega_{_0}}\$.

The standard form for a 2nd order bandpass is:

$$H\left(s\right)=K\cdot \frac{2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}\,s}{s^2+2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}\,s+\omega_{_0}^2}$$

Where \$K\$ is the voltage gain. You can now solve for \$K\$.

It may be convenient to set \$\tau_{_1}=\frac{L_1}{R_1}\$ and \$\tau_{_2}=R_2\,C_1\$.

Then you should find:

$$K=\frac{1}{1+\frac{\tau_{_2}}{\tau_{_1}}}$$

With all values set to 1, as you show, this means \$K=\frac12\$ or \$-6\;\text{dB}\$.

---

Let's re-examine \$H\left(s\right)\$ with some light from above.

We know that \$\omega_{_0}\cdot \tau_{_0}=1\$, so it follows that: \$\tau_{_0}=\sqrt{L_1\,C_1\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)}\$

Let's follow through with some algebra and replacements:

$$\begin{align*}
H\left(s\right)&=\frac{\frac{1}{C_1\left(R_1+R_2\right)}\,s}{s^2+\frac{R_2\,C_1+\frac{L_1}{R_1}}{L_1\,C_1\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)}\,s+\frac{1}{L_1\,C_1\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)}}\\\\
&=\frac{\frac{\frac{L_1}{R_1}}{L_1\,C_1\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)}\,s}{s^2+\frac{R_2\,C_1+\frac{L_1}{R_1}}{L_1\,C_1\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)}\,s+\frac{1}{L_1\,C_1\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)}}\\\\
&=\frac{\tau_{_1}\,\omega_{_0}^2\,s}{s^2+\left(\tau_{_1}+\tau_{_2}\right)\omega_{_0}^2\,s+\omega_{_0}^2}
\end{align*}$$

From this, we can fathom that the damping factor is \$\zeta=\frac12\,\left(\tau_{_1}+\tau_{_2}\right)\omega_{_0}\$. (Look back at the definitions for \$\alpha\$, \$\omega_{_0}\$, and \$\zeta\$ earlier above.)

Looking only at the numerator now, we know that \$K\,2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}=K\,2\left(\frac12\,\left(\tau_{_1}+\tau_{_2}\right)\omega_{_0}\right)\,\omega_{_0}=\tau_{_1}\,\omega_{_0}^2\$ or that \$K\left(\tau_{_1}+\tau_{_2}\right)=\tau_{_1}\therefore K=\frac{\tau_{_1}}{\tau_{_1}+\tau_{_2}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{\tau_{_2}}{\tau_{_1}}}\$

Q.E.D.

---

I hadn't realized you wanted the branch current through \$R_2\$ and \$C_1\$ divided by \$V_\text{IN}\$, before. But everything is present above to develop it. Take the equation for \$V_Y\$ from above and divide it by the branch impedance, \$R_2+Z_{C_1}\$:

$$\begin{align*}
I&=\frac{V_Y}{R_2+Z_{C_1}} = V_\text{IN}\,\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_1}{Z_1}}\,\frac{1}{R_2+Z_{C_1}}\\\\&\therefore\\\\
\frac{I}{V_\text{IN}}&=\frac{L_1\,C_1\,s^2}{L_1\,C_1\left(R_1+R_2\right)s^2+\left(R_1\,R_2\,C_1+L_1\right)s+R_1}
\end{align*}$$

But the easier way to see the above result is to just go back to your \$\frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}\$ transfer function. \$V_\text{OUT}\$ is riding on top of \$C_1\$. So the branch current is \$I=\frac{V_\text{OUT}}{Z_2}\$. All you have to do is:

$$\frac{I}{V_\text{IN}}=\frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}\cdot \frac{I}{V_\text{OUT}}=\frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}\cdot\frac1{Z_2}=\frac{V_\text{OUT}}{V_\text{IN}}\cdot \bigg[C_1\, s\bigg]$$

Nothing at all difficult to see.

### Final note to OP on using sympy for problems such as the above

Since you expressed an interest in [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) (which I most certainly recommend to you), I'll disclose below what I did to save myself time (and mindless mistakes) when creating the equations I used above.

(I also recommend including a numeric solver, [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/). I use Sage with sympy, myself. Be sure to google around to see how others have installed both on your operating system of choice.)

I entered the following, to get started:

```
var('vin vout vy l1 c1 r1 r2 s')
z2=1/s/c1
z1=(s*l1)*(z2+r2)/(s*l1+z2+r2)
hs=simplify(1/(1+r1/z1)/(1+r2/z2))
```

Then I write the first line below, which printed out the second line:

```
hs
l1*s/(l1*s*(c1*r2*s + 1) + r1*(c1*s*(l1*s + r2) + 1))
```

Well, sympy has its own style of generating "best output" by factoring things. I didn't like it much, so I wrote something to just grab the denominator, expand it (un-factor it) out, and then factor it back over 's', instead. The first line is what I wrote; the second line is what it gave back:

```
factor(expand(fraction(hs)[1]),s)
r1 + s**2*(c1*l1*r1 + c1*l1*r2) + s*(c1*r1*r2 + l1)
```

Now, that looks a lot better.

Pretty easy, right??

But then I wanted "standard form." So now the following (a is \$\alpha\$, w0 is \$\omega_{_0}\$, etc):

```
a=(r1*r2*c1+l1)/2/l1/c1/(r1+r2)
w0=sqrt(r1/l1/c1/(r1+r2))
zeta=a/w0
```

I knew that \$K=\frac{H\left(s\right)}{\left[\frac{2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}\,s}{s^2+2\zeta\,\omega_{_0}\,s+\omega_{_0}^2}\right]}\$, so I added:

```
K=simplify(hs/((2*zeta*w0*s)/(s**2+2*zeta*w0*s+w0*w0)))
```

To see what that was:

```
K
l1/(c1*r1*r2 + l1)
```

Well, this immediately told me something important. Divide top and bottom by \$L_1\$ and I get: \$\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_2\,C_1}{\frac{L_1}{R_1}}}\$. (The denominator is unitless, as it must be. And so I kept both factors in terms of time so that the unit cancellation was obvious. )

That's probably enough for now. You get the idea. It's really easy!

Sage, if you use it, has its own "shell variable" called "SAGE_STARTUP_FILE" which you can set to some file. When you start Sage from a shell command, it will load that file and execute the lines as if you typed them. Saves time. In my case, to get the bits of sympy I often use, my file starts this way:

```
%colors linux
from sympy import *
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import radsimp, signsimp
from sympy.simplify.radsimp import collect_sqrt
```

Because it's easy to do and because I sometimes want to look at different Butterworth filters without having to go find a manual on it, I add these lines, as well:

```
def Butterworth(n):
    r = solve( 1+(-1)**n*x**(2*n), x )
    t = []
    for a in r:
        if real( a ) < 0:
            t.append( a )
    t.sort( key = lambda tup: real( tup ) )
    u = []
    var( 's' )
    if ( len( t ) - 2*int( len( t ) / 2 ) ) == 1:
        u.append( s + 1 )
        t.pop( 0 )
    for i in range( len( t ) / 2 ):
        scnd = collect(expand((s - t[2*i])*(s - t[2*i+1])), I, evaluate=False)[1]
        n, d = fraction( scnd )
        co = [collect_sqrt( simplify( r ) ) for r in Poly( n, s ).all_coeffs()]
        spwr = simplify( s**(len( co )-1) )
        ufactor = 0
        for j in co:
            ufactor = ufactor + spwr * factor( j/d )
            spwr = simplify( spwr/s )
        u.append( ufactor )
    return u
```

This allows me to write:

```
for x in Butterworth(2): simplify(x)
s**2 + sqrt(2)*s + 1
```

If I want the numbers, instead, then:

```
for x in Butterworth(2): simplify(x.n())
s**2 + 1.4142135623731*s + 1.0
```

Let's try something a little higher order, done both with irrationals as well as just approximate real numbers:

```
for x in Butterworth(4): simplify(x)
s**2 + s*(sqrt(4 - 2*sqrt(2)) + sqrt(2*sqrt(2) + 4) + 2*sqrt(sqrt(2) + 2))/4 + 1
s**2 + s*(-sqrt(4 - 2*sqrt(2)) + 2*sqrt(2 - sqrt(2)) + sqrt(2*sqrt(2) + 4))/4 + 1
for x in Butterworth(4): simplify(x.n())
s**2 + 1.84775906502257*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.765366864730179*s + 1.0
```

Ah! But I wanted a 12th order Butterworth:

```
for x in Butterworth(12): simplify(x.n())
s**2 + 1.98288972274762*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.84775906502257*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.58670668058247*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.21752285801744*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.765366864730179*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.261052384440103*s + 1.0
```

Well, I'm insane now. I'm going to design myself a 23rd order Butterworth filter because... well because I can:

```
for x in Butterworth(23): simplify(x.n())
s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.98137189207266*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.9258345746956*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.83442260301091*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.70883880909298*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.55142258140884*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.36510628643731*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.15336064422973*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.920130075462304*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.669759224341972*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.406912026105268*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.136484826729342*s + 1.0
```

Now, do you know where I can find the constants for a 23rd order Butterworth? (If so, I'll just use this: "for x in Butterworth(100): simplify(x.n())" and push up the ante a bit.)

In short, you can develop your own functions and solutions for a variety of electronic needs. I have. Pretty much anything is at your fingertips.

I sometimes want to develop my own diode equations for various LED devices. I grab a bunch of random devices from the bag and make three measurements on each one. (I do have to use a 5-digit multimeter, or better, to get necessary precision and reasonable accuracy. I have a 6.5 digit one from HP.) In this way, I can collect up the LED parameters and examine their distributions. This tells me a lot about their manufacturer and their strategies in selling them through the supplier I bought from.

So I wrote this:

```
def diode():
    print( "This program uses 3 diode measurements to extract parameters." )
    print( "You will need to have taken these measurements beforehand." )
    print( "Enter each point as [ <diode current>, <diode voltage> ]." )
    print( "" )
    TA= int( input( "Enter the ambient temperature in Celsius (default is 27 C): " ) or "27" )
    print( "" )
    VT= 8.61733034e-5 * ( 273.15 + TA )
    POINTS= []
    vd, id, N, ISAT, RS= symbols( "vd id N ISAT RS" )
    for i in range(3):
        pid, pvd= input( "Enter point " + str(i) + ": " ).split()
        POINTS.append( { vd: pvd, id: pid } )
    EQS= []
    for i in range(3):
        EQS.append( Eq( POINTS[i][vd], RS*POINTS[i][id] + N*VT*ln(POINTS[i][id]) - N*VT*ISAT ) )
    print( POINTS )
    print( EQS )
    ANS= solve( EQS, [ RS, N, ISAT ] )[0]
    print( "RS   = " + str(ANS[0]) )
    print( "N    = " + str(ANS[1]) )
    print( "ISAT = " + str(exp(ANS[2])) )
```

This program generates the model parameters I want for any LED I have in my hand from just three distinct measurement points, \$\left(V_i, I_i\right)\$.

---

By the way, if you think I'm joking about 100th order Butterworth? Here it is:

```
for x in Butterworth(100): simplify(x.n())
s**2 + 1.99975326496332*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.99777974992394*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.99383466746626*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.98792191091036*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.98004731543312*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.97021865230955*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.95844562124353*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.94473984079535*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.9291148369156*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.91158602959666*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.89217071765509*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.87088806165973*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.84775906502257*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.82280655327089*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.79605515152123*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.76753126017739*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.73726302887638*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.70528032870818*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.67161472273654*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.63629943485005*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.59936931697418*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.56086081467666*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.52081193120006*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.47926218995722*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.43625259552638*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.39182559318463*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.34602502701955*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.29889609666037*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.25048531267141*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.20084045065177*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.15001050408656*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.09804563599626*s + 1.0
s**2 + 1.0449971294319*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.990917336864815*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.935859628521147*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.87987833971183*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.823028717210218*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.765366864730179*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.706949687558514*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.647834836396299*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.588080650464608*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.527746099930746*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.466890727711811*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.405574590713025*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.343858200558819*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.281802463875165*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.219468622182091*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.15691819145569*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.0942129014192853*s + 1.0
s**2 + 0.0314146346236414*s + 1.0
```

Of course, that's all theoretical! Assuming a sufficiently precise VNA even existed, you might be [sitting around for a long time tweaking it using its time domain function](https://nuwaves.com/using-time-to-save-time-tuning-filters/).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122619/discussion-on-answer-by-jonk-what-are-the-final-steps-to-arrive-at-the-transfer).