Efficiency of transistor amplifier
Is it true that efficiency of audio amplifier- made of transistor, improve as time of usage increases? (I mean the circuit is made of discrete components). Since the conductivity of semiconductor increase with temperature.


To help get an answer can you edit the question to include a link to I read this point somewhere.

read here @MISC {585234,
TITLE = {Temperature vs diode voltage in Shockley's equation},
AUTHOR = {LvW (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/40274/lvw)},
HOWPUBLISHED = {Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange},
NOTE = {URL:https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/585234 (version: 2021-09-02)},
EPRINT = {https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/585234},
URL = {https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/585234}
}

Rajesh R - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More rules in the [tour] & [help])

Is improve as time of usage increases asking about (a) improvements as the equipment "warms up" after being switched on from cold (b) as the equipment "ages" with prolonged used?

There is generally no truth to your statement but perhaps in some cases, minor improvements can be made better or worse depending on the design.  Heatrise is always a source of concern for reliability.
Semiconductors have different losses  (Vce*Ic) in linear mode from conduction mode and different temperature coefficients for Vbe (NTC) and Tk (PTC), neither are significant in making the audio amp more efficient. This answer shows thermal effects from the Shockley Equation.
Bipolar Transistors do get faster and have more current gain with heat but efficiency is not the primary effect of these parameters.
Audio amps are very different for Class AB bipolar to Class D MOSFET where efficiency is worse with hotter MOSFETs as the RdsOn increases as switches which contradicts your assumption.
